# How can I use Java to connect to/embed the ThingSpeak server (API) in our own Android studio app?

Tags: api, iot, android-connectionservice, custom-application

How can our own custom app read data from the thingSpeak server using the thingSpeak API?

As I have seen from other resources, the code I tried to use to connect my application to the thingSpeak server contained numerous errors, which prevented me from succeeding.
I want to use my application to connect to the ThingSpeak server, but I keep getting errors.

The following permissions have been added to the app's manifest file:

'`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`'

```
 [Internet permission code] [1]
```

Then, incorporate the Volley library into the build.gradle file for the project and sync it:
[Volley library code ] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPs3D.png)`

```
'implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
```

`added all volleyball libraries to the request: [Imported all the libraries] [3]`

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
```

After that i have created a new ACTIVITY 5 and write cide there:`package com.example.simp;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String fd = MainActivity5.class.getSimpleName();
    private String url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/ 2046669/feeds.json?api_key=ABCABCABACXYZ&results=10";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response. Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the response string.
                        Log.d(fd, "Response: " + response);
                        // Parse the response string and display the data in your app's UI.
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                        Log.e(fd, "Error: " + error.toString());
                    }
                });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

[Code with libraries] [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs851.png)
[code with fetch request] [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tykzf.png)

Comment: Please share the sample code here

Comment: Ok boss, i am sharing